# How to shift an element in grid from right to left

Tags: html, css

I have this learning projet.

This is the second section in the website, I have a question, I have this 'red' textbox that contain Text, on the right side of the screen, I would want to shift it a little bit to the left side, to make the same effect as the other text in the other section. But when I add something like `margin-right:`  the whole page shift to the left, how can I bypass this ?

thank you verry much :)

Best Paint you will ever see... hahaha

[image]

```css
@media (min-width: 1024px) {

  * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
  }


  ::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
  }


.Blogtwos{
  background:rgb(48, 150, 28);

}

  .explicationPage{
    display: grid;    
    grid-template-columns: auto 36% auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    height: 100vh;
  }


  .ImageBlogB{
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 2/2;
    justify-self: center;
    display: grid;
  }

  .ImageBlogB > img{
    max-width: 56%;
    min-width: 56%;
    margin-top: 15%;
    justify-self: center;  
  }


  .Desccapone{
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 1/1;
    margin-top: 2.8%;
    justify-self: center;
  }

  .desccaptionB{
      grid-column: 1/1;
      grid-row: 2/2;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 126%;
      margin-top: 12.4%;
      margin-left: 13%;
      text-shadow: 4px 4px 13px black;

  }

  .Desccaptwo{
    justify-self: center;
    grid-column: 3/3;
    grid-row: 2/2;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 126%;
    margin-top: 2.4%;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 13px black;
    background: red;
  }




}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/large.css" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mini.css" /> -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>NextOnEarth</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Page d'explication -->

    <div class="Blogtwos">
      <div class="explicationPage">
        <div class="ImageBlogB">
          <img src="images/green.png" alt="ProjetDesc" id="ImageBlocksi" />
        </div>

        <div class="Desccapone">
          <h2 id="titleDesc">Pourquoi le projet "Next On earth"</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="desccaptionB">
          <p class="desc1">
            Le but est de pouvoir rendre accessible le plus simplement possible
            la
            <span style="background-color: yellow">
              diffusions d'information</span
            >
            sur le thème de l'environnement,
            <span style="background-color: yellow">en un clique</span> vous
            pouvez consulter des articles sans même avoir besoin de faire des
            recherches sur le sujet.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="Desccaptwo">
          <p class="desc2">
            En obligeant les utilisateurs à se connecter pour pouvoir utiliser
            la platform, "next on earth" recoltes les information
            d'inscriptions,
            <span style="background-color: yellow"
              >qui seront utilisé dans le but de financer des projets lier au
              thème de l'environnement</span
            >, vous pouvez retrouver plus d'informations à ce sujet dans
            l'onglet "Légal"
          </p>
          <p class="desc3">
            Projet réalisé dans l'optique de la réalisation d'un projet
            personnel
          </p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>


    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script src="statistiques.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
.Blogtwos{
  background:rgb(48, 150, 28);

}

  .explicationPage{
    display: grid;    
    grid-template-columns: auto 36% auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    height: 100vh;
  }


  .ImageBlogB{
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 2/2;
    display: grid;
  }

  .ImageBlogB > img{
    max-width: 52%;
    min-width: 52%;
    margin-top: 15%;
    justify-self: center;  
  }


  .Desccapone{
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 1/1;
    margin-top: 2.8%;
    justify-self: center;
  }

  .desccaptionB{
      grid-column: 1/1;
      grid-row: 2/2;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 126%;
      margin-top: 12.4%;
      margin-left: 13%;
      text-shadow: 4px 4px 13px black;

  }

  .Desccaptwo{
    justify-self: center;
    grid-column: 3/3;
    grid-row: 2/2;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 126%;
    margin-top: 2.4%;
    margin-right: 35%;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 13px black;
    background: red;
  }




}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/large.css" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mini.css" /> -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>NextOnEarth</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Page d'explication -->

    <div class="Blogtwos">
      <div class="explicationPage">
        <div class="ImageBlogB">
          <img src="images/green.png" alt="ProjetDesc" id="ImageBlocksi" />
        </div>

        <div class="Desccapone">
          <h2 id="titleDesc">Pourquoi le projet "Next On earth"</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="desccaptionB">
          <p class="desc1">
            Le but est de pouvoir rendre accessible le plus simplement possible
            la
            <span style="background-color: yellow">
              diffusions d'information</span
            >
            sur le thème de l'environnement,
            <span style="background-color: yellow">en un clique</span> vous
            pouvez consulter des articles sans même avoir besoin de faire des
            recherches sur le sujet.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="Desccaptwo">
          <p class="desc2">
            En obligeant les utilisateurs à se connecter pour pouvoir utiliser
            la platform, "next on earth" recoltes les information
            d'inscriptions,
            <span style="background-color: yellow"
              >qui seront utilisé dans le but de financer des projets lier au
              thème de l'environnement</span
            >, vous pouvez retrouver plus d'informations à ce sujet dans
            l'onglet "Légal"
          </p>
          <p class="desc3">
            Projet réalisé dans l'optique de la réalisation d'un projet
            personnel
          </p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Bouttons Credits et Legal-->
    <!-- 
    <div>
      <a
        class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
        id="creditsButton"
        href="./Credits.html"
        >Credits</a
      >
    </div>

    <div>
      <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="legalButton" href="./Legal.html"
        >Legal</a
      >
    </div>
 -->
    <!-- Sources des scripts-->

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script src="statistiques.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please illustrate with a screenshot to understand your problem better.

Comment: @m4n0 Click on "Run code snippet" then "Full page" to understand

Comment: @MB_ If you understood, you can answer as well. He updated the question with the screenshot and the requirement.

Comment: Do you need padding? https://nimb.ws/oS0tsG

Comment: @m4n0 I never said I couldn't answer :)

Comment: Hey, So I added a new snippet with what I mean, I added a margin on the text element, so it shift itself to the left, but, It's not very clear on the snippet, but the logo in the middle shift to the left as well, is there is any way I can fix this ?

Comment: @HypeLiveUsb, Salut, I will put the three divs desccaptionB, ImageBlogB, Desccaptwo in another div with for class: flexbox and justify-content: space-between or space-around

Comment: @HypeLiveUsb, Otherwise, as you use Bootstrap, you put the 3 divs desccaptionB, ImageBlogB, Desccaptwo in a "container" div then you add col-md-4 to them

Comment: Noted, thank you sir ! Merci :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can use justify content, start or end.
For Example:

```
.explicationPage{
    display: grid;  
    justify-content: end;  
    grid-template-columns: auto 36% auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    height: 100vh;
  }
```